# Sort List-box Conditionally without changing the Row-source

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access, listbox, vba

If I got a list box say lstABC with 3 columns A, b & c.
And there is 3 sorting buttons say btnSortA, btnSortB, btnSortC.
Is there a way to use the on_click event on the buttons that allow the user to sort lstABC without changing lstABC.rowsource every time?

I was trying to achieve something in the line of this:

```
Private sub btnSortA_Click()
 lstABC.Orderby = "ColumnA ASC"
 me.lstABC.OrderByOn = True
End Sub
```

Sure I could build SQL strings and set/requery lstABC.rowsource = string(for every button), but I am looking for something simple and efficient that don't overcomplicated things. Thanks

Comment: Maybe if there is a way to change the sort order in SQL to sort on IIF(Some condition) is true... and build this into the original rowsource

Comment: That would looks smthing like this `SELECT A,B,C FROM TableName IIf(chk_A OR chk_B OR chk_C, IIf(chk_A," ORDER BY A;", IIf(chk_B, " ORDER BY B;", " ORDER BY C;"), ";")` but in that case it would use checkboxes and not buttons

Comment: This looks promising and is more in the line with what I am thinking of, now if I can just get it working

Comment: Don't forget to call `.Requery` on the listbox in the `onClick` event of your checkboxes then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you can not make it simplier than changing the row source. You could also read all rows in the listbox and reinsert all the rows in the right order with `.addItem`...

```
Private Sub sortListbox(criteria As String)
  Dim strSQL As String

  strSQL = "SELECT A,B,C FROM TableName" _
    & " ORDER BY " & criteria

  Me.yourListboxController.RowSource = strSQL
  Me.yourListboxController.Requery
End Sub
```

And you just add in the click event :

```
Private Sub btnSortA_Click()
  Call sortListbox("A")
End Sub

Private Sub btnSortB_Click()
  Call sortListbox("B")
End Sub

Private Sub btnSortC_Click()
  Call sortListbox("C")
End Sub
```

I do not think you can have simplier than that.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for some hidden access build in function I missed...  anyway now I just got to align the rest of the code with this